# Remove memcached from ubuntu

Tags: installation

I have install memcached from source using these commands

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://danga.com/memcached/dist/memcached-1.2.4.tar.gz
tar zxvf memcached-1.2.4.tar.gz
cd memcached-1.2.4
./configure
make
make install
```

Now i want to remove it, how can i remove it from ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

cd /usr/local/src/memcached-1.2.4

---

make uninstall

---

if there is`n have make uninstall command you can just delete this folder   /usr/local/src/memcached-1.2.4